# Shell variables cannot be used as arguments for another shell command

Tags: bash, shell

I tried to read some file names from a txt file, pass them into shell variables, and use them as arguments for a command. But could not get I expect.

The content of files.txt:

```
directory1/to/foo1 directory2/to/foo1
directory1/to/foo2 director2/to/foo2
...
```

I tried to compare the two files listed in files.txt like this:

```
cat files.txt | while read -r f1 f2; do cmp -b $f1 $f2; done
```

but I got errors:

```
cmp: missing operand after '-b'
```

I realized that $f1 and $f2 did not get referenced properly. How should I modify my command line?

Comment: There's probably a blank line in the file, so the variables were set to empty strings.

Comment: What you have looks mostly correct (although `$f1` and `$f2` should both be quoted). Does the error occur on the first line of input, or later?

Comment: You should always quote your variables.

Comment: when I quoted $f1 and $f2, I still get the same error. somehow $f1 and $f2 could not be passed as the arguments for `cmp`

Comment: Your example of `files.txt` works perfectly. Please, provide an example that really crashes. If the current example crashes for you, there is a problem on your environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can protect the cmp from invalid file names with some pre-checks as follows:

```
cat files.txt | while read -r f1 f2 extra; do  [ -r "$f1" ] && [ -r "$f2" ] && cmp -b "$f1" "$f2"; done
```

This should hopefully avoid the errors.  Of course, you could ignore errors, too, but that's probably not a good idea.  Please be aware that cat is unnecessary in this code.  You can just redirect stdin as follows:

```
while read -r f1 f2 extra; do  [ -r "$f1" ] && [ -r "$f2" ] && cmp -b "$f1" "$f2"; done <files.txt
```

One last thing: the read command will put the first white space delimited value in f1 and the second and remaining items in f2.  That is, if the input file has extra stuff after the second file name, if will be shoved into f2.  To avoid this, consider putting a dummy variable at the end of your read to get the extraneous fields if they exist.  I've done just that with the third variable, extra.

The additional syntax I added to your cmp command is this:

```
[ -r "$f1" ] && [ -r "$f2" ] && cmp -b "$f1" "$f2"
```

Essentially, bash will first make sure that $f1 is a readable file and if so, it will check that $f2 is a readable file and only then will it proceed to the cmb command.

Answer (score 0):

I know what's going on for my previous problem: in `files.txt` I have an extra line at the end of the file, which made `read -r` reads in empty contents. Since the other files are identical, no output was shown by `cmp`. But when `cmp` encounters the last empty `$f1` and `$f2`, an error is shown:

`cmp: missing operand after '-b'`

Thank you guys for all your above answers. Appreciate them a lot!